# how can I rename a table / move to a different schema in sql DB2?

Tags: db2, rename, db2-luw

I am trying to rename a table in db2 like so

```
rename table schema1.mytable to schema2.mytable
```

but getting the following error message:

```
the name "mytable" has the wrong number of qualifiers.. SQLCODE=-108,SQLSTATE=42601
```

what is the problem here.... I am using the exact syntax from IBM publib documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot change the schema of a given object. You have to recreate it.

There are severals ways to do that:

- If you have only one table, you can [export](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html) and [import](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html)/[load](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html) the table. If you use the IDX format, the DDL will be included in the generated file. If using another format, the table has be created.
- You can recreate the table by using:

  `Create table schema2.mytable like schema1.mytable`
- You can extract the DDL with the [db2look](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html) tool
- If you are changing the schema name for a schema given, you can use [ADMIN_COPY_SCHEMA](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022035.html)

These last two options only create the table structure, and you still need to import the data. After having create the table, you insert the data by different ways:

- Inserting directly

  `insert into schema2.mytable select * from schema1.mytable`
- Via load from cursor
- Via a Load or import from file (The file exported in the previous step)

The problem is the foreign relations, because they have to be recreated.

Finally, you can create an [alias](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000910.html). It is easier, and you do not have to deal with relations.

Comment: hi thanks - thought there might be a command to simply move the table into the new schema, but your way of creating a new table in the other schema from the actual table, then inserting does the job for me. but more cumbersome but that's fine.

Comment: There's also an `ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE` system stored procedure that does exactly what it says, including all dependencies.

Comment: @mustaccio I also thought ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE could do that, but the documentation does not have the option to provide a different schema: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055069.html

Comment: More information about how to move tables: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0907db2outages/

Comment: Stupid me.I'd take my comment back but it's too late.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily rename a table with this statement:

```
RENAME TABLE SCHEMA.TABLENAME TO NEWTABLENAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not renaming table in provided example, you're trying to move to different schema, it's not the same thing. Look into [db2move](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0002079.htm) tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to rename a table in the same schema, you can use like this.

```
RENAME TABLE schema.table_name TO "new_table_name";
```

Otherwise, you can use tools like DBeaver to rename or copy tables in a db2 db.

Answer (score -1):

What if you leave it as is and create an alias with the new name and schema.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't actually move the table, it just creates a pointer to it.  This _can_ be useful in some situations, but will not help when the table actually needs to be moved.

Answer (score -2):

Renaming a table means to rename a table within same schema .To  rename in other schema ,db2 call its ALIAS:

db2 create alias  for

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't actually move the table, it just creates a pointer to it. This can be useful in some situations, but will not help when the table actually needs to be moved.  Also, this is identical to an existing answer.